# Styling area tags

Tags: css, imagemap, area

I have a pair of image-maps on which I want their areas to high-light when the mouse hovers over them.

I am using jquery to detect the mouseover and assigning a css class. The assignment works and I can confirm the new class name. But, the area does not high-light.

My best guess is perhaps area is not a recognised HTML tag. Can anyone suggest how I could get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example we can see?

Comment: Considering it sounds like an error with your code, you need to post the relevant code parts, including HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the html area tag is not a visual element that you can style. But, this other question: [Visible Area tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906734/visible-area-tag) points to a very useful jQuery plugin you could use: http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to make an image of what you want to overlay and place it using width and height percentages. Makes it responsive as well.