# cursor pointer in html <area> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a jsp like this

```
<%@ include file="commonheader.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function passValue(stateid,cityid)
{
if(cityid=="0")
{
    document.forms["test"].action="locator/city.jsp"
    document.forms["test"]["stateid"].value=stateid;
    document.forms["test"].submit();
}
else
{   
    document.forms["test"].action="locator/area.jsp"
    document.forms["test"]["stateid"].value=stateid;
    document.forms["test"]["cityid"].value=cityid;
    document.forms["test"].submit();
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div align="center">     
<table width="70%" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="80%" align="center"><img src="images/map.jpg" width="550" height="500" border="0" usemap="#Map">
<form id="test" name="test" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="stateid" />
<input type="hidden" name="cityid"/>       
<map name="Map">
<area shape="rect" coords="81,291,180,305" alt="Maharashtra" onclick="passValue('15','0') />
</map>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Form is getting submitted and the values are getting passed correctly. But the problem here is the cursor is not a pointer but a default.
I have even tried specifying the style attribute in  tag like style="cursor:pointer;" but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `href="javascript:void(null);"` to the area tag will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are doing anything wrong. If you are looking for a quick solution, just wrap the `MAP` and `IMG` in a `DIV` tag and style that:

http://jsfiddle.net/8PrD9/

This topic may be helpful if you need a more elaborate solution:

[Visible Area tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906734/visible-area-tag)

HTML5 spec on `MAP` for reference:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-map-element.html

I can't find anything which explicitly states that these elements cannot be styled, but that seems to be the general consensus from the research I have done.

Comment: Thank you! But i've tried something like this <area href="javascript:void(0);" > </area> and it's working fine now...