# Highlight <area>

Tags: javascript, dom

Sometimes I want to see exactly where are the `<area>` tags on pictures on the page.

Is there a way in Javascript to change color or hide a part of the image corresponding to the area tags ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visible Area tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906734/visible-area-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [mapper.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/). It allows you to highlight areas inside image maps upon mouse over.