# map <area> background image not being displayed

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to display a background image for a map area when a user hovers over it. Currently I've specified a separate id for each area and I have written a javascript function that triggers when the area is hovered over. To this function I pass the element id and by looking at the console I know that the function is being called with the correct element yet the background is not being displayed! Currently I've only implemented the functionality in the products tag.

I also tried giving the area a z-index of 9999 and fixed width/min-width and height/min-height.

Here is the website https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14863356/OsmosysV3/index.html

NOTE: Just an fyi to others who are facing this problem, Chrome or safari require that you have name attribute declared for map even though it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Visible Area Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906734/visible-area-tag/1908347#1908347) image map areas are not visually represented and hence no css is reflected on them. If you want a hover over effect over your maps, then you can find a way to do so by following [this link](http://www.svennerberg.com/2008/09/imagemap-rollover/)

It's probably not the neatest way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need javascript? In CSS could you not do:

```
#welcome{
  height: 300px; // or whatever
  &:hover{
    background: url("welcome.jpg")
  }
}
```

Then same for the other elements.

Comment: @verticas1 That's not working. I think you may have misunderstood my question. I'm talking about hovering over the area element of the image map. If you hover over products in the #slideshow and then hover over the product names, you'll find that there are <area> tags for each of them. I want the area tags' background to change when I hover over them. Currently they have a transparent background.