# html map area hover effect

Tags: html, css, tags

```
<img alt="" src="img/Immagini di base NoPain Project/Parti Donna/corpo-donna-fronte.png" width="477" height="672" usemap="#woman-body" id="corpo_d" />
<map id="woman-body">
    <area shape="rect" coords="260,140,200,50" href="#" id="body_one"  />
    <area shape="rect" coords="200,150,160,220" href="#" id="body_two" />
</map>
```

when the mouse is over one of the two areas,  I would like that the area was highlighted by a border.

**This is the css, but it does not work.**

```
area#body_one:hover
{
    border:1px solid #0F0;  
}
```

Comment: Duplicate, read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag

Comment: but I do not want to use jquery, but simply the css

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that will work. What you need is a plugin like [imagemapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) — it's quite easy to set up and use and you can do a lot of really nice things with it.