# PNG images - Trigger :hover only on non-alpha channels

Tags: css, image, hover, png, alpha

Say you want to put very complex shaped images on a site, for example a country or state

http://www.nc4ea.org/nc4ea/assets/Image/TX-small.jpg

and you want this to react to `:hover` precisely when the cursor touches the border, entering the country.
Given the image is in PNG format, is there a way to add CSS to only non-alpha channels? In other words, the `:hover` effect should take place when you hover over the actual visible part of the image (ie the country, the non-transparent channels) but not when you hover over a transparent/alpha channel.

Comment: may be this question will be helpfull, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag

Comment: @sarhov hard-coding borders for a country?? absolutely not.