# image appear over other image on hover over

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an image map where there is one main image, and when you hover over certain areas different images come up.

Something like this [How to apply Hovering on html area tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag)   but instead of creating an outline it would show different images.

I do not want to usse jQuery and would prefer to rely on CSS and HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any suggestions @enhzflep ?

Answer (score 0):

You could cover smaller blank images over the large main image and use the hover code separately for each image

The non hover image is a "blank" png and the hover is the desired result
Just use the code for each "blank" image with the main image in the background with z-index of "0"

Comment: and by "blank" I mean completely transparent

Comment: that sounds good...as a newbie to coding I'm getting lost in the css...this bit in particular  <area shape="poly" onmouseover='myHover(this);' onmouseout='myLeave();' coords="2,0,604,-3,611,-3,611,166,346,165,345,130,-2,130,-2,124,1,128,1,126" href="" alt="imgmap201293016112-0" title="imgmap201293016112-0" class="imgmap201293016112-area" id="imgmap201293016112-area-0" />

Answer (score 0):

As said in previous answer, you could do this by using the ***z-index*** property. But try setting the main image's z-index as 0, and all small images(that you want to show over main image) as lower than 0.

And finally, activate by swapping the *z-index* between values lower or higher than 0 on mouse hover.

Hope this helps :)