# How to make specific shaped divs

Tags: css

I am working on a project that has a map on it. Each section of the map highlights as you hover over it, and it hyperlinks to a corresponding website. On some of the areas, I can just size a div and absolutely place it with overlaying background image set to opacity:0. On Hover I change the opacity to 1 and all is good. Some of the other areas are too specific of a shape, so I've used transform to rotate the div, but I can't get specific enough. I'm getting too much overlap. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. I'm looking for any help. I've tried many things and I'm in a rut. Here is where I'm at now.

https://jsfiddle.net/4w3emy4o/2/

```
           <div class="erieBasin">
              <a href="http://erca.org/" target="_blank"><div id="essex"></div></a>
              <a href="http://www.lowerthames-conservation.on.ca/" target="_blank"><div id="thames"></div></a>
              <div class="kettle"></div>
              <div class="close"></div>
            </div>


.erieBasin {
    position:absolute;
    width:900px;
    height:589px;
    z-index:100;
    background-image: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/2h4b23k.jpg);  
}
#essex {
    position:absolute;
    top:270px;
    left:275px;
    width:91px;
    height:72px;
    background-image: url(http://i63.tinypic.com/28s6cew.jpg);
    opacity: 0;
}
#essex:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
#thames {
    position:absolute;
    top:222px;
    left:325px;
    width:215px;
    height:60px;
    background-image: url(http://i66.tinypic.com/2nl8dwx.jpg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-32deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-32deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-32deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

#thames:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Probably better-off using image-maps. The sections of the map are then arbitrary polygons. Here's a question I dealt with once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag/12667751#12667751

Comment: @enhzflep thanks for the response. I might be in over my head for that. I don't think I have time to learn that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG alternative:.

**1- SVG Clip-path** On this first snippet there's a svg clip-path ( helper: [**clip-path-generator**](http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator) ) applied on an image and a blury clone without the clip-path, both inside a container. A low opacity color layer was added to let the highlight even more clear. The clip-path area gets highlighted on `:hover`

*ps.1: made with the polygonal lasso tool quick and careless since its just an example.*
*ps.2: on this clip-path generator, you can click and drag a picture from your Desktop into the canvas. You can easily find more clip-path generators around the web like [**this one**](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).*
*ps.3: you can build svg shapes on graphic softwares (like Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator) instead.*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: lavender;
}

.clipped {
  cursor: pointer;  
}

.clipped:hover {
    -webkit-filter: contrast(200%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: contrast(200%);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid indigo;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.color {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.back {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  filter: blur(2px);  
}

.clipped {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

#clip1 {
  
  /*Chrome,Safari*/
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(578px 230px,581px 228px,584px 228px,587px 230px,591px 232px,597px 236px,618px 239px,624px 238px,642px 241px,667px 245px,674px 245px,677px 243px,666px 238px,661px 240px,653px 238px,647px 233px,643px 234px,627px 234px,624px 230px,634px 223px,639px 225px,638px 221px,646px 213px,652px 207px,656px 204px,660px 206px,668px 203px,678px 200px,686px 203px,690px 199px,715px 195px,713px 192px,714px 186px,711px 188px,705px 188px,694px 185px,692px 180px,688px 183px,686px 178px,672px 175px,664px 181px,663px 176px,659px 175px,642px 172px,641px 170px,634px 168px,634px 160px,631px 157px,625px 157px,625px 155px,619px 155px,597px 158px,587px 167px,589px 171px,584px 173px,574px 183px,574px 186px,567px 188px,565px 189px,577px 190px,579px 193px,578px 196px,575px 196px,569px 202px,567px 206px,562px 210px,569px 215px,572px 217px,574px 226px);

/*Firefox*/
clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");

/* iOS support inline encoded svg file*/
-webkit-mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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) no-repeat;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class=container>
<img class=back src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2h4b23k.jpg" alt=img>
  <div class=color></div>
<img id=clip1 class=clipped src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2h4b23k.jpg" alt=img onClick="window.location.href = 'http://erca.org/'">
</div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
    <polygon points="578 230,581 228,584 228,587 230,591 232,597 236,618 239,624 238,642 241,667 245,674 245,677 243,666 238,661 240,653 238,647 233,643 234,627 234,624 230,634 223,639 225,638 221,646 213,652 207,656 204,660 206,668 203,678 200,686 203,690 199,715 195,713 192,714 186,711 188,705 188,694 185,692 180,688 183,686 178,672 175,664 181,663 176,659 175,642 172,641 170,634 168,634 160,631 157,625 157,625 155,619 155,597 158,587 167,589 171,584 173,574 183,574 186,567 188,565 189,577 190,579 193,578 196,575 196,569 202,567 206,562 210,569 215,572 217,574 226">
    </polygon>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

**2- SVG shape** Second snippet, more simple: single pic without filters/clip-path plus a solid svg shape made on Adobe Illustrator with the pen tool:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;  
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
polygon {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
  fill: green;
}

polygon:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2h4b23k.jpg" alt=pic>

<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="900px" height="589px" viewBox="0 0 900 589">
<polygon onClick="window.location.href = 'http://erca.org/'" points="364.333,317.333 357,311 348,310.667 347,307.667 349.333,305.667 352.333,305 351.667,302.333 
 349.667,300.667 351,292.667 353,291 356.667,292.667 357.333,295 359.333,283.667 369,276.333 370.667,269.667 371,258.333 
 374.667,260 384,257.333 391.333,253.333 392.333,256.667 396.667,253.333 399.667,257 406,254 406.667,251.333 413.667,246.333 
 416.667,246.333 419.333,244.667 419.333,239.333 425,239.333 426,233 435,228.333 438.667,231 442,227 451.334,221.333 456,221 
 455,209.333 461.667,208 463.334,206 463.334,200.333 472,199 476.667,197.333 476.334,195 473.667,194 480.334,193 487.334,191 
 487.334,187 489.667,184 492.334,187 497,184.333 506,183 510.667,184 516.667,190.667 510,188.333 505.334,189.667 505,196 
 508.334,196.667 511.334,199 507.667,202.667 509,205 510.334,206.667 515.667,205.667 523,206.667 523.667,208 517.334,213.333 
 515,215.333 513,215.333 511.667,219.333 507.667,218.667 509,224 506,226.667 504.334,229.333 501,231.333 493.334,231.333 
 496,232.667 492.667,233.667 492.334,235.667 486.667,236.667 481,242.333 478,243.333 473,249.333 468,252.333 462,256.333 
 457.667,261 448.667,267.333 447.667,272.333 448,277.333 446,279.667 445,283.667 445,286.333 441.333,288.667 439.333,287 
 440.667,281 438.667,280.667 435,280.667 433,282.667 432.667,287 428.333,286.333 422.667,286.667 410.667,291 399.667,297 
 399.667,298.333 395.333,299.333 384.667,305.333 380.667,307 375.667,310.333 371,313 "/>
</svg></div>
```

**3- Multiple SVG shapes** On this 3rd snippet theres several SVG paths automatically generated by the Adobe Illustrator 'trace image' feature.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;  
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
path {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
  fill: green;
}

path:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2h4b23k.jpg" alt=pic>

  <svg x="0px" y="0px"
  width="900px" height="589px" viewBox="0 0 900 589" >
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C8C3D9" d="M621,1c-0.636,1.399-0.761,2.768-0.419,4.341
 c1.288,5.921-1.485,9.547-7.905,10.679c-0.95,0.167-2.531,0.377-2.684,0.898c-1.604,5.508-4.256,2.165-6.962,1.147
 c-4.679-1.76-5.131,3.151-6.943,5.281c-3.527,4.146-5.729,9.505-11.569,11.264c-1.419,0.428-1.953,1.404-2.299,2.891
 c-0.71,3.05-2.289,5.953-2.643,9.017c-0.671,5.813-4.39,5.419-8.105,4.179c-2.642-0.881-3.365-0.332-3.359,2.167
 c0.009,4.188-3.457,7.866-1.296,12.546c0.842,1.823,0.274,4.33-3.159,5.473c-2.983,0.992-3.423,4.852-2.261,7.854
 c1.438,3.717-1.079,4.791-3.444,5.985c-2.556,1.289-5.006,2.491-7.343-0.882c-2.991-4.316-6.322-8.387-10.6-11.637
 c-3.953-3.005-12.177-2.994-15.286,0.469c-0.489,0.545-0.911,1.771-0.633,2.284c1.83,3.369,0.619,7.16,1.848,10.807
 c1.311,3.889-2.386,7.726-4.255,11.417c-1.538,3.039-3.374-0.044-5.052,0.043c-1.697,0.088-6.197-2.187-3.298,3.035
 c1.008,1.814-0.603,1.767-1.466,2.357c-3.137,2.146-6.206,4.12-4.275,8.977c0.929,2.339-2.713,5.296,0.35,7.795
 c1.486,1.213,1.08,2.853,1.468,4.281c1.473,5.423-0.634,8.65-4.091,12.339c-3.202,3.417-0.505,8.896-2.967,12.843
 c-2.478,3.972-4.549,7.736-8.539,11.184c-7.964,6.881-18.967,4.844-26.576,11.621c-3.059,2.724-12.111,0.939-13.022-2.76
 c-1.326-5.387-1.95-9.334-8.728-7.408c-0.107,0.03-0.533-0.488-0.539-0.758c-0.148-6.147-5.59-8.284-8.714-12.242
 c-2.616-3.315-2.942-8.495-4.056-12.907c-0.349-1.38,1.187-1.665,2.218-2.233c9.833-5.427,20.175-10.22,25.302-21.328
 c0.867-1.88,1.934-3.697,1.381-5.619c-1.202-4.176-0.723-8.294-0.009-12.382c1.189-6.809,0.988-13.581,0.194-20.396
 c-1.816-15.602-1.411-31.279-1.292-46.932C460.038,17.966,458.553,9.496,457,1C511.667,1,566.333,1,621,1z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C8C3D9" d="M654,1c-1.459,4.093-2.451,7.463,3.889,8.63
 c2.641,0.486,0.557,4.53-0.251,5.708c-2.024,2.95-1.739,4.355,1.1,6.399c2.42,1.742,1.534,5.813-1.242,6.345
 c-2.741,0.525-2.993,1.515-1.683,3.643c1.161,1.886,1.613,3.65-0.93,4.954c-1.075,0.552-1.649,1.594-1.379,2.938
 c0.391,1.936,9.94,10.392,11.923,10.52c6.692,0.435,9.054,3.03,7.106,9.193c-0.749,2.37-0.68,4.82-1.629,7.093
 c-1.699,4.071-0.15,6.377,3.749,6.83c-3.163,4.634-5.624,9.72-6.222,15.303c-0.681,6.361-4.133,10.502-9.287,13.319
 c-4.215,2.305-4.483,2.578-0.778,6.031c1.454,1.354,3.263,2.433,4.394,4.008c1.738,2.422,5.572,3.85,2.437,8.526
 c-2.145,3.198,2.735,5.244,4.477,7.81c3.456,5.092,8.597,8.285,13.326,11.952c2.838,2.2,1.724,6.142,3.908,8.83
 c2.632,3.237,6.126,6.185,6.084,10.974l0.021-0.016c-1.344,0.014-2.687,0.027-4.03,0.041c-0.095-0.073-0.19-0.146-0.285-0.219
 c0.11,0.058,0.222,0.115,0.332,0.173c1.663,1.468,3.472,2.84,3.64,5.426c-2.015,0.84-3.79-0.621-5.667-0.399
 c-1.424-1.277-3.134-1.837-5.004-1.995c-0.725-1.096-1.695-1.817-3.024-1.996c-2.773-3.101-7.28-5.208-10.078-3.263
 c-3.538,2.46-7.716,3.731-10.993,6.593c2.444-0.464,5.746-0.583,6.852-2.201c4.523-6.622,9.499-1.483,14.263-1.173
 c0.352,1.656,1.682,1.832,3.019,1.996c1.328,1.516,3.094,1.933,5.001,1.997c0.26,1.08,0.169,2.573,1.901,2.287
 c2.654-0.439,4.746,1.129,7.095,1.769l-0.063-0.059c0.33,0.332,0.66,0.665,0.99,0.997l0.078,0.086c0,1.824,0,3.648,0,5.474
 c1.039-1.736,1.496-3.439,0.612-5.169c0.265-0.256,0.53-0.512,0.795-0.768c0.971,4.885,5.968,6.076,8.737,9.348
 c1.701,2.01,5.149,2.066,7.431,1.447c5.988-1.624,11.214,1.253,16.764,1.999c2.883,0.388,5.468,1.907,8.689,1.217
 c2.896-0.62,3.501,2.743,3.408,4.254c-0.146,2.39-0.949,6.021-4.659,4.932c-3.617-1.062-6.592-1.194-9.538,1.383
 c-1.153,1.01-2.597,0.322-3.749-0.356c-3.121-1.843-6.277-3.152-10.535-0.404c2.106-7.662-3.097-6.917-6.721-7.154
 c-5.736-0.376-11.12-0.367-15.694-5.201c-1.467-1.551-5.282-0.905-5.277-4.864c0.001-0.843-1.523-0.992-2.592-0.87
 c-3.587,0.41-7.128,0.412-10.521-1.16c-1.245-0.577-3.062-0.892-3.768,0.189c-2.468,3.775-4.699,1.733-7.863,0.856
 c-6.231-1.727-12.831-2.236-19.316-2.854c-1.343-0.128-2.2-0.072-2.614-1.35c-0.708-2.185-2.231-2.735-4.406-3.288
 c-3.385-0.861-3.124-4.222-3.127-6.961c-0.004-4.049-1.406-6.059-5.722-4.599c-0.312,0.105-0.788,0.417-0.902,0.315
 c-5.343-4.809-10.547-0.277-15.832,0.099c-4.289,0.306-8.663,0.191-12.938-0.293c-3.081-0.35-3.781-7.101-0.749-9.654
 c3.717-3.13,4.754-5.617,0.393-9.094c-1.753-1.397-1.614-4.155-1.551-6.44c0.078-2.83-0.568-4.931-4.012-4.703
 c-5.134,0.34-7.73-3.567-10.224-6.853c-1.228-1.618-2.159-3.59-3.654-5.145c-0.934-0.971-1.568-1.847-0.232-3.351
 c2.548-2.866,1.308-5.649-2.715-5.854c-2.35-0.119-3.493,0.116-2.215-2.814c1.361-3.121-2.762-1.951-3.471-3.714
 c0.292-0.406,0.546-0.818,0.856-1.184c1.353-1.589,5.25-1.969,3.479-4.977c-1.381-2.346-4.454-1.646-6.904-1.001
 c-1.11,0.293-2.152,0.845-3.352,1.33c-0.644-1.307-1.034-2.764-0.384-3.741c2.414-3.624,3.686-6.994,0.554-11.017
 c-0.921-1.184-1.085-3.425,1.324-4.537c4.451-2.056,5.894-5.44,4.704-10.28c-1.581-6.427,1.897-10.801,8.45-9.804
 c4.261,0.648,4.884-0.493,5.07-4.514c0.135-2.928,0.716-6.037,1.264-9.032c0.223-1.219,0.521-2.85,1.933-3.322
 c6.363-2.13,9.415-7.516,12.709-12.674c2.687-4.207,5.984-2.49,9.011-0.744c2.817,1.627,4.507,2.378,3.991-2.127
 c-0.485-4.242,3.521-2.279,4.419-2.089c2.909,0.618,4.872,1.149,4.632-2.914c-0.09-1.516,1.628-2.002,2.318-3.101
 c0.68-1.083,2.357-2.304,1.431-3.446c-3.565-4.395-0.121-5.811,2.851-7.572C627.85,1.771,627.88,1.309,628,1
 C636.667,1,645.333,1,654,1z M627.774,96.561c0.114,0.042,0.229,0.084,0.344,0.126c-0.078-0.141-0.156-0.28-0.234-0.421
 C627.847,96.364,627.811,96.462,627.774,96.561z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C8C3D9" d="M802,1c-0.426,3.974-5.394,6.576-9.513,4.525
 c-2.843-1.416-5.139-2.34-7.427,0.611c-0.272,0.351-0.907,0.709-1.295,0.638c-7.041-1.294-11.535,5.22-17.9,5.816
 c-5.02,0.472-9.374,2.919-14.091,4.253c-1.397,0.396-3.277,0.732-4.415,0.124c-6.881-3.686-12.454,0.396-18.314,2.767
 c-1.063,0.431-2.364,1.708-3.163,0.877c-5.367-5.586-12.122-0.241-17.975-2.441c-2.52-0.947-5.66-0.19-7.36-3.167
 c-0.561-0.981-1.691-1.009-2.686-0.942c-5.136,0.341-10.402,0.158-15.354,1.314c-3.036,0.708-5.997,2.834-8.817,4.229
 c-4.017,1.989-7.229,0.527-10.744,0.866c-4.286-0.727-4.203-3.537-2.052-5.922c3.287-3.644,0.969-5.944-1.745-7.097
 C655.403,5.862,655.939,3.73,657,1C705.333,1,753.667,1,802,1z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C8C3D9" d="M377.034,231.039c-2.095,0.656-3.039,3.054-5.38,3.424
 c-2.867,0.452-4.274-0.133-6.533-2.822c-5.705-6.793-0.559-12.35,0.548-18.314c0.729-3.926,2.179-7.622-0.117-11.549
 c-0.699-1.194-0.134-2.814,0.318-4.324c1.044-3.481,2.462-6.877,2.575-10.63c0.122-4.067,1.5-7.21,5.979-8.651
 c3.294-1.061,2.326-4.714,1.17-6.239c-2.172-2.869-0.053-2.504,1.445-2.82c6.979-1.472,14.012-2.721,20.936-4.414
 c3.675-0.899,7.367-2.261,8.507-6.67c0.492-1.906,2.325-2.103,3.78-2.874c6.585-3.492,11.701-8.476,14.175-15.628
 c0.865-2.503,2.878-1.622,4.336-2.19c1.428-0.558,1.915,0.805,2.176,2.029c0.552,2.598,1.178,5.18,1.694,7.784
 c0.618,3.117,2.132,5.284,5.343,6.337c3.519,1.155,4.234,4.119,2.619,6.945c-1.763,3.084-0.617,3.779,2.129,4.005
 c0.644,0.053,1.305-0.149,1.956-0.142c2.082,0.025,5.723,2.936,6.368,5.051c0.461,1.512,9.039,7.033,10.531,6.388
 c2.639-1.14,5.846-0.763,8.066-2.167c8.357-5.285,18.569-5.563,27.011-10.479c2.251-1.312,2.41-3.805,3.597-5.709
 c0.754-1.209,1.065-3.389,2.81-2.681c1.51,0.612,0.878,2.709,0.437,4.062c-2.568,7.857-6.248,15.012-13.566,19.557
 c-2.477,1.537-3.346,3.274-2.438,6.223c1.071,3.481-1.568,6.72-5.221,7.573c-3.253,0.761-7.87-0.61-8.115,5.45
 c-0.077,1.902-3.144,2.633-5.504,2.255c-3.302-0.53-5.572,0.272-5.774,4.181c-0.117,2.289-1.632,3.772-3.832,3.941
 c-3.197,0.245-4.688,1.791-4.033,4.839c1.794,8.363-5.457,9.4-9.985,12.746c-4.739,3.501-10.943,3.074-15.83,6.216
 c-1.899,1.221-3.715,2.204-4.005,4.671c-0.039,0.331-0.063,0.933-0.162,0.948c-5.838,0.88-6.214,8.414-11.737,9.628
 c-3.102,0.682-5.476,2.481-7.102,5.074c-0.792,1.264-1.602,2.465-2.996,1.985c-3.834-1.317-7.611,1.294-11.419-0.066
 c-0.672-0.24-1.992-0.089-2.325,0.375c-2.836,3.949-7.436,3.187-11.277,4.403c-0.766,0.242-1.604,0.511-2.373,0.428
 c-1.097-0.119-3.534-9.888-2.905-10.821c0.732-1.088,2.352-1.452,1.698-3.641c-2.19-7.343-0.208-9.713,7.658-9.866
 c0.329-0.007,0.658-0.058,1.825-0.165c-1.998-0.509-3.245-0.782-4.464-1.149c-1.291-0.389-2.6-0.821-2.635-2.54
 c2.291-3.906,0.413-6.242-3.01-7.998c-0.688-2.771,3.086-4.252,1.998-7.552c-1.996,2.396-4.075,4.355-1.954,7.513
 C374.69,225.783,378.237,227.526,377.034,231.039z M409.229,234.246c-0.189-0.194-0.381-0.386-0.576-0.574
 c0.108-0.894,0.216-1.787,0.323-2.681l0.172-0.143l-0.137,0.177c-6.573,4.952-13.984,5.702-21.92,3.872
 c9.794,3.404,19.137,1.464,29.509-1.315C413.275,232.726,411.271,233.622,409.229,234.246z M387.193,211.881
 c-7.218-1.396-7.218-1.396-8.229,2.738C381.812,213.672,384.503,212.776,387.193,211.881z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C8C3D9" d="M558.16,88.179c0.58,6.603,0.58,6.603,11.612,5.345
 c-0.596,1.087-1.541,1.646-2.642,2.118c-3.789,1.623-4.415,3.504-0.313,5.597c0.927,0.473,1.911,1.089,1.866,2.149
 c-0.244,5.699,3.357,5.012,7.987,3.74c-5.516,7.755,1.912,11.103,4.421,15.652c1.604,2.908,3.72,7.709,9.146,6.74
 c1.13-0.202,1.565,1.131,1.777,2.093c0.788,3.561,1.402,7.103,5.055,9.188c1.153,0.658,0.195,1.628-0.682,2.294
 c-4.853,3.684-5.207,8.313-2.829,13.549c0.32,0.705,0.546,2.151,0.246,2.338c-5.873,3.652-6.453,11.752-12.69,15.039
 c-3.34,1.76-5.692,4.687-7.738,7.604c-2.935,4.185-5.099,4.87-9.127,1.652c-3.963-3.165-14.702-3.195-19.99-0.743
 c-2.924,1.355-6.414,1.97-9.663,2.021c-4.246,0.066-7.815,1.783-11.196,3.74c-2.596,1.503-4.641,1.232-6.088-0.761
 c-5.609-7.726-13.104-5.796-20.268-3.843c-2.964,0.808-4.958,0.415-7.528-1.492c2.348-1.879,4.751-3.54,6.845-5.526
 c6.834-6.485,9.552-14.298,9.787-23.916c0.16-6.58-1.96-14.657,5.369-19.678c2.277-1.56,1.857-11.045,0.605-13.203
 c-2.896-4.989-3.097-10.98,0.854-14.332c2.201-1.867,3.317-6.591,8.07-4.635c0.898,0.37,1.736-1.261,2.505-2.146
 c5.018-5.775,5.704-12.458,4.448-19.652c-0.864-4.953,1.776-7.305,6.898-6.422c4.947,0.853,7.105,5.112,10.169,8.236
 c1.735,1.77,3.185,3.815,4.791,5.713c2.301,2.718,4.82,4.041,7.926,1.115C557.91,87.896,558.035,88.036,558.16,88.179z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C8C3D9" d="M350.393,309.262c4.419-1.638,4.624-4.51,3.326-8.054
 c-0.846-2.309-0.276-4.546,1.089-7.227c3.142,4.104,4.908,2.597,5.589-1.303c0.882-5.046,2.727-8.743,7.496-11.918
 c4.146-2.761,6.746-8.107,5.562-14.072c-0.509-2.563-0.416-4.323,3.442-4.89c3.93-0.576,8.261-0.77,11.842-3.1
 c0.921-0.599,1.629-1.023,2.481,0.146c0.331,0.454,1.567,0.897,1.64,0.799c3.882-5.332,10.535-1.058,15.475-4.889
 c5.665-4.393,6.402-3.441,13.354-12.226c0.786-0.994,1.914-1.268,3.091-1.404c1.672-0.193,2.61-1.086,3.171-2.71
 c1.667-4.835,5.245-6.225,10.439-6.523c4.248-0.244,7.716-3.642,11.396-5.885c0.546-0.333,0.856-1.03,1.369-1.443
 c4.185-3.368,6.484-6.305,6.863-11.347c0.355-4.721,5.65-2.063,6.678-5.301c0.909-2.864,0.884-6.229,5.748-5.824
 c3.486,0.29,6.877-1.422,7.921-5.38c0.597-2.265,2.29-2.107,3.864-2.336c3.451-0.501,7.196-0.484,7.258-5.517
 c0.009-0.767,0.895-1.751,1.735-1.427c5.754,2.215,10.214-2.694,15.611-2.779c1.977-0.03,3.449,0.037,4.005,1.733
 c0.846,2.582-1.8,1.626-2.84,2.216c-2.492,1.414-4.876,3.53-8.354,2.04c4.377,2.044,4.959,8.251,11.049,8.428
 c-1.296,2.432-2.811,4.452-1.098,7c1.335,1.984,2.342,3.337,5.125,2.377c2.433-0.84,5.12-0.938,8.275,0.446
 c-4.607,3.379-9.447,5.452-12.699,9.595c-0.734,0.935-1.441,1.717-1.671,2.921c-1.178,6.172-4.55,8.858-10.574,10.728
 c-4.596,1.426-9.162,3.742-13,6.644c-8.216,6.212-15.94,13.071-23.895,19.631c-1.024,0.844-2.416,1.426-2.46,2.938
 c-0.069,2.388-1.465,2.591-3.359,2.468c-2.561-0.168-4.239,1.68-6.157,2.95c-0.749,0.496-1.497,1.377-0.54,1.926
 c3.563,2.045,0.965,5.43,1.806,8.101c0.77,2.445-1.615,4.237-4.186,4.567c-2.425,0.312-4.978,0.627-7.34,0.198
 c-3.26-0.591-5.939-1.114-6.6,3.301c-0.185,1.238-1.322,1.726-2.702,1.635c-9.302-0.614-17.793,2.171-25.235,7.385
 c-7.75,5.429-16.35,9.031-24.742,13.12c-4.212,2.052-8.158,4.461-11.301,7.978c-1.176,1.314-2.453,2.025-3.782,0.663
 c-1.841-1.886-3.265-4.035-6.116-4.823C355.919,310.118,353.311,309.975,350.393,309.262z M468.999,218.988
 c1.001,0.698,1.862,1.837,3.442,1.094c-0.89-1.531-2.38-0.634-3.478-1.051c-0.396-1.292-1.165-1.987-2.517-1.309
 c-1.877,0.942-1.081,2.832-1.408,4.322c-3.108,0.046-4.899,3.008-7.782,3.53c-3.745,0.68-5.836,3.165-7.214,6.466
 c-1.074,0.314-2.266-1.008-3.461,0.171c1.362,1.046,2.424,0.786,3.418-0.226c1.956-0.921,4.771-1.086,5.934-2.24
 c3.658-3.636,3.368-3.929,8.174-1.98c-0.5-2.164-1.235-4.308,0.874-5.769C466.076,220.669,466.365,218.264,468.999,218.988z
  M442.853,234.325c-0.278,0-0.557-0.003-0.834,0.014c-0.008,0-0.004,0.202-0.006,0.311c0.278,0.001,0.557,0.002,0.835,0.003
 C442.848,234.544,442.848,234.435,442.853,234.325z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C8C3D9" d="M573.974,217.017c1.159-2.683,2.744-5.366-0.009-8.045
 c0.269-0.069,0.536-0.14,0.805-0.209c-0.074-0.117-0.147-0.234-0.221-0.352c-0.182,0.202-0.362,0.404-0.543,0.607
 c-0.798,0.211-1.949,0.158-2.337,0.677c-2.41,3.228-4.624,2.451-6.951-0.354c1.768-1.251,4.003-1.907,4.234-5.118
 c0.172-2.383,2.715-5.166,5.033-5.743c3.841-0.956,6.362-3.646,6.6-6.496c0.246-2.954-3.771-3.951-6.67-4.84
 c2.941-6.566,7.265-11.184,14.091-13.003c1.752-0.468,2.443-1.596,1.435-2.852c-2.139-2.663-0.05-3.9,1.464-5.31
 c2.042-1.9,4.526-3.252,5.878-5.959c0.886-1.774,2.989-1.038,4.591-0.962c7.021,0.333,13.999,0.298,20.709-2.2
 c1.218-0.454,1.404,0.436,1.737,1.133c0.622,1.304,1.653,2.67,3.015,1.871c4.936-2.895,3.765,1.031,3.946,3.377
 c0.304,3.905,0.256,7.996,5.841,8.061c1.186,0.014,1.593,0.96,2.162,1.804c1.534,2.273,2.595,6.38,6.244,1.836
 c0.227-0.282,1.499,0.203,2.255,0.43c3.957,1.189,7.976,1.885,12.128,1.791c0.931-0.021,2.263-0.511,2.741,0.585
 c2.43,5.561,5.165,3.19,7.707,0.266c1.457-1.676,2.832-1.9,4.793-1.099c1.984,0.811,4.041,1.465,6.285,1.301
 c1.843-0.134,2.796,1.134,4.205,2.23c4.011,3.12,8.975,4.98,13.386,7.632c3.545,2.132,7.832,0.371,11.256,2.544
 c0.813,0.517,2.496-1.585,2.414,0.659c-0.039,1.073-0.617,2.479-2.313,2.861c-3.234,0.73-6.379,1.856-9.61,2.604
 c-5.912,1.367-11.822,2.834-17.811,3.752c-3.203,0.491-8.96,0.853-9.421-0.334c-1.483-3.827-5.156-3.897-7.356-6.106
 c-0.124-0.124-0.563,0.064-1.051,0.138c-0.447,2.492,2.271,1.789,3.16,2.953c0.985,1.289,3.781,1.411,3.003,3.851
 c-0.718,2.249-3.001,1.57-4.756,1.697c-4.282,0.309-8.638-0.457-12.825,1.288c-2.045,0.852-3.523,1.884-4.976,3.721
 c-3.333,4.217-6.671,9.107-11.186,11.519c-4.335,2.316-8.171,5.2-12.202,7.833c-2.721,1.778-4.488,4.386-2.629,8.022
 c1.278,2.5-0.518,2.971-2.365,2.827c-11.115-0.863-22.184-1.949-31.722-8.644c-2.586-1.815-5.273-3.12-8.625-3.242
 c-7.425-0.271-8.035-1.439-5.496-9.043c0.579,2.534,3.426,2.889,4.67,4.851c0.555,0.875-2.536,1.679,0.07,2.108
 c0.718,0.119,1.671-0.299,1.881-1.273c0.228-1.056-0.08-1.987-1.053-2.544C577.73,219.056,575.846,218.047,573.974,217.017z
  M581.986,200.97c0.332-0.332,0.665-0.665,0.998-0.998c4.132-3.227,6.46-8.467,12.001-10.121
 c-7.747,2.024-7.747,2.024-11.958,10.164c-0.332,0.333-0.666,0.665-0.999,0.998c-0.339,0.338-0.678,0.677-1.018,1.015
 c-0.323,0.67-0.647,1.339-0.972,2.009c-0.681,0.324-1.361,0.649-2.041,0.975c-0.031,0.312-0.916,0.401-0.233,0.897
 c0.065-0.314,0.131-0.629,0.197-0.942c0.679-0.327,1.356-0.655,2.035-0.982c0.325-0.665,0.65-1.33,0.976-1.995
 C581.311,201.648,581.648,201.31,581.986,200.97z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C8C3D9" d="M359.599,337.555c-2.142-3.257-3.584-5.479-5.056-7.683
 c-3.299-4.94-10.645-7.911-16.383-6.871c-4.896,0.887-9.532,2.402-13.899,4.784c-4.921,2.684-10.783,1.667-15.843,3.952
 c-0.69,0.312-1.986-0.265-2.803-0.758c-6.143-3.711-12.589-6.699-19.409-8.976c-2.101-0.701-3.59-2.31-2.139-5.079
 c1.509-2.88-0.795-5.964-0.097-8.819c1.407-5.754,1.661-11.479,1.605-17.392c-0.034-3.599,0.883-8.313,6.78-7.685
 c0.722,0.077,1.726-0.262,2.235-0.772c4.94-4.941,13.406-5.865,19.976-3.15c5.89,2.435,12.251,5.232,18.362,5.139
 c4.632-0.072,10.009-0.016,14.51-1.907c3.706-1.556,7.154-0.385,10.695-0.696c1.726-0.151,1.946,0.883,1.729,2.204
 c-0.35,2.135-0.716,4.269-1.144,6.39c-0.229,1.14-0.317,2.454-2.16,1.289c-3.146-1.989-4.191,0.369-4.837,2.748
 c-0.472,1.74-0.745,3.618-0.646,5.409c0.152,2.749,0.814,5.381-2.798,6.656c-1.145,0.404-1.731,2.048-0.965,3.479
 c0.856,1.602,2.248,2.397,4.08,2.381c4.199-0.04,7.746,1.26,10.674,4.473c1.636,1.796,2.764,3.573,1.346,5.71
 C360.557,326.688,360.754,331.77,359.599,337.555z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C8C3D9" d="M541.897,223.594c-3.604,0.122-7.297,0.694-10.816-0.561
 c-5.817-2.074-11.211,0.934-16.826,1.188c-1.28,0.058-2.6,1.087-3.253-0.841c-0.505-1.493,0.432-2.113,1.417-3.187
 c3.281-3.573,7.521-5.716,11.332-8.491c1.007-0.732,2.707-1.17,2.341-2.856c-0.393-1.804-1.928-2.77-3.62-2.958
 c-2.467-0.275-4.972-0.215-7.461-0.262c-2.909-0.054-4.855-0.672-2.687-4.082c1.311-2.062,1.185-3.836-1.397-4.709
 c-1.893-0.64-4.271-0.857-3.526-3.724c0.787-3.029,4.292-3.276,5.672-2.524c6.29,3.427,11,0.154,16.242-2.471
 c4.63-2.318,10.469-0.52,14.932-2.778c3.862-1.955,7.172-3.44,11.502-2.286c2.143,0.571,4.03,1.374,6.358,2.927
 c-3.896,1.44-7.563,1.757-10.987,3.326c-7.2,3.302-12.261,8.819-17.555,14.205c-2.596,2.64-2.939,6.886,0.041,8.116
 c4.356,1.797,3.778,6.981,7.686,8.622C542.083,220.581,542.348,222.236,541.897,223.594z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C8C3D9" d="M553.266,210.74c1.375,4.441,4.651,7.87,6.453,12.037
 c-9.276,3.021-16.313-0.348-19.465-9.296c-0.489-1.389-1.227-2.224-2.675-2.618c-3.632-0.988-3.353-4.164-1.764-5.849
 c7.02-7.442,14.258-15.02,25.419-15.558c4.25-0.205,8.46,2.007,12.905,0.556c1.266-0.413,2.682,0.501,2.996,2.034
 c0.327,1.595-1.028,2.82-2.067,3.037c-5.313,1.104-6.646,6.026-9.528,9.445c-0.416,0.493-0.531,1.238-0.945,1.733
 c-1.026,1.229-4.618,0.979-3.122,3.356c1.208,1.918,2.093,4.865,5.429,5.125c3.201,0.249,3.031,3.473,3.738,5.578
 c0.418,1.244-0.271,3.252-2.216,3.245c-2.49-0.009-5.436,1.354-7.225-1.712c-2.014-3.449-4.002-6.913-6.003-10.369
 C554.856,210.899,554.445,210.425,553.266,210.74z M546.033,213.039c-1.264,1.095-1.085,2.113,0.369,3.304
 c-0.156-1.266-0.285-2.304-0.414-3.342c0.182-0.222,0.381-0.433,0.534-0.673c0.04-0.062-0.063-0.214-0.1-0.325
 C546.293,212.349,546.163,212.693,546.033,213.039z M549.6,205.654c-2.092-0.381-4.03,0.289-5.804,1.431
 c-0.07,0.045,0.332,1.353,0.765,1.566C547.44,210.073,547.553,206.323,549.6,205.654z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this. I'm just having a time trying to implement it. I will keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: SVG is powerful, but a bit tricky. It has a lot of potential pitfalls. If you don't have to, I would generally choose a simpler approach.

Comment: So, with the 2nd snippet, I'd like it to highlight only when hovered. With the example you provided, it seems the svg is the size of the entire div. Is it possible to zreo in on the just the polygon?

Comment: @Greg very simple: just set the hover on the specific polygon, not on the entire svg area. The second snippet got updated with a `:hover` state, check it again please;

Comment: Wow. Thank you for all this effort. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Although I like freestock's answer, I want to suggest a different approach.

There is an element, that is specifically designed for such purposes: [`map`](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/image-maps.html). You can define polygons with it.

The basic usage is:

```
<img src="shapes.png" usemap="#shapes" >
 <map name="shapes">
  <area shape=rect coords="50,50,100,100">
  <area shape=rect coords="25,25,125,125" href="red.html" >
  <area shape=poly coords="450,25,435,60,400,75,435,90,450,125,465,90,500,75,465,60" href="yellow.html">
 </map>
```

<sup>example taken from the w3 link</sup>

Comment: Downvoted, reread the question, and upvoted as this is the correct answer. SVG would not be the appropriate suggestion.

Comment: I would not be so harsh to downvote the SVG answer, as it surely is a valid way to tackle the problem. I agree though, that it is some kind of overkill.

Comment: I don't downvote to no apparent reasons. I do that so others will see that's not the logical answer. SVG would not be the logical answer and honestly create more work rather than the appropriate MAP and area tags

Answer (score 0):

Can you try an imagemap? They are pretty lightweight and there are lots of easy to use generators out there now: https://www.image-maps.com/