# Multiple CSS on hover effects on one image

Tags: css, imagemap

I have an image map with several coordinates, I would like an on hover effect for each section. The effect should only appear for the section which is currently on hover and the other sections should stay as normal

Image map:

```
 <!-- Calculations based on an original image (width,height)=(3106,2071) -->
<img src="http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/uploads/160410_151558_5a93c70d827455Ae.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" style="height: 715px; width: 1075px;">
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.google.com" shape="poly" coords="382,37,522,37,589,157,521,276,382,278,313,158">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.facebook.com" shape="poly" coords="171,158,309,160,379,279,311,399,170,398,101,279">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.example.com" shape="poly" coords="315,400,380,281,517,283,590,401,520,520,384,521">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.mail.google.com" shape="poly" coords="524,521,593,405,729,404,801,522,732,644,592,641">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.random.com" shape="poly" coords="737,397,801,281,943,281,1013,400,945,521,803,520">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.ebay.com" shape="poly" coords="525,277,595,159,731,158,800,277,733,396,592,398">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.instagram.com" shape="poly" coords="735,157,803,37,941,37,1011,156,943,276,804,276">
</map>
```

Desired on hover effect:

```
 img.grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag  - seems like a similar question

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that with map area, but you can do it with svg:

```
<svg  id="Map" style="height: 715px; width: 1075px;">
   <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com"><polygon points="382,37,522,37,589,157,521,276,382,278,313,158"/></a>
   <a xlink:href="http://www.facebook.com"><polygon points="171,158,309,160,379,279,311,399,170,398,101,279"/></a>
   <a xlink:href="http://www.example.com"><polygon points="315,400,380,281,517,283,590,401,520,520,384,521"/></a>
   <a xlink:href="http://www.mail.google.com"><polygon points="524,521,593,405,729,404,801,522,732,644,592,641"/></a>
   <a xlink:href="http://www.random.com"><polygon points="737,397,801,281,943,281,1013,400,945,521,803,520"/></a>
   <a xlink:href="http://www.ebay.com"><polygon points="525,277,595,159,731,158,800,277,733,396,592,398"/></a>
   <a xlink:href="http://www.instagram.com"><polygon points="735,157,803,37,941,37,1011,156,943,276,804,276"/></a>
</svg>
```

and css:

```
svg#Map {background:url(http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/uploads/160410_151558_5a93c70d827455Ae.jpg); 
background-size:cover;
}

#Map polygon {fill:rgba(0,0,0,0)}
#Map polygon:hover {
 fill:rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
}
```

see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grassog/akgs3zyt/

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to make a lightbox appear on click would you?

<!-- Calculations based on an original image (width,height)=(3106,2071) -->
<img src="http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/uploads/160410_151558_5a93c70d827455Ae.jpg" 

alt="" usemap="#Map" style="height: 715px; width: 1075px;">
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.google.com" shape="poly" coords="382,37,522,37,589,157,521,276,382,278,313,158" class="et_pb_lightbox_image">

Comment: I'd say with onclick event (something like 
`<polygon points="735,157,803,37,941,37,1011,156,943,276,804,276" onclick="lightbox()"/>` )
but maybe this deserve a new question?