# default cursor not working in IE and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a map element and area as rect

```
<map name="Map">           
 <area class="showCursor" shape="rect" coords="1,3,10,8">  
</map>
```

I want the cursor to be default when I hover on that area and added a class `showCursor`

```
area.showCursor {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Now this is showing default cursor in chrome, but on IE and Mozilla it is showing the hand.

How can I make it default cursor in all the browsers.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.showCursor:hover {cursor: default;}`?

Comment: can you put a image in area and create fiddle.If area is empty it is not possible to see the cursor

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but same result @Bret DeWoody

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply Hovering on html area tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
<img usemap="#Map" src="yourimagesource" height="120" width="100" />
<map name="Map">           
 <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,120,100" href="#" alt="Sun" class="crossbar">
</map>

area.crossbar{
    cursor: default;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this CSS will work

```
area(Your Class name) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

OR you can try this one also

```
area(yuor class name){
    cursor:auto;
}
```