# How to create mouse hover effect to irregular shape on image map

Tags: html, css

How to create mouse hover effect to irregular shape on image map? The irregular shapes can be quite complicated,not poly/rectangle/triangle/circle but lantern or animal shape. Would this be possible ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to highlight this shape? Or just the mouse over will occur in this shape?

Comment: This may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag/12667751#12667751

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes I hope to highlight the outline of the irregular shape

Comment: Is @phelpsiv answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try an working with an SVG vector image to select specific irregular shapes.

CSS would look like:

```
.shape:hover {
    fill: green;
}
```

and html SVG:

```
<svg version="1.0" width="291.000000pt" height="300.000000pt">

<g class="rabbit"fill="#000000" stroke="none"  transform="translate(0.000000,300.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">

<path .../>
```

Example: http://codepen.io/phelpsiv/pen/rLYvrp

Comment: +1 for SVG. Adobe Illustrator is great for creating SVGs automatically. If you're using a specific image map, you can trace over it in Illustrator, export the SVG, then use this method to make any given shape a hover state. (you can also make the standard state transparent)

Comment: It's a great idea but what about `on image map`?

Comment: The best I could find on that was **Harshad Hirapara answer below** to the best of my knowledge that's as close as you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

Try based on cordinates:

```
<map id="honeycomb" name="honeycomb">
    <area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="493,23,572,65,573,159,491,204,415,158,415,67" href="" target="" />
    <area shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="651,22,732,66,732,158,652,203,574,158,573,66" href="" target="" />
    ...
</map>
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/v9wZV/)