# Highlighting image map areas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an image map, which implements the famous plugin for make it dynamically resize to any screen. Now I wished to implement something for make areas highlight when the user mouses over (and obviously, the light gets removed if he/she mouses out).

I tried to implement a part famous plugin from this guy: @enhzflep, but it seems it's not working. (I say a part because he tells how to apply hover on a rect and on a poly shape, but I only do need poly).

Check this post for his plugin: [how to apply hover on an image map area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag).

Source of the image: [Source](http://www.giratempoweb.net/gw11/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Hogwarts_Professors_by_Belegilgalad-e1392461785761.jpg)

This is the HTML/JavaScript

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="homestyle.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//THE PART I NEED OF THE @enhzflep PLUGIN.
var hdc;

// shorthand func
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

// takes a string that contains coords eg - "227,307,261,309, 339,354, 328,371, 240,331"
// draws a line from each co-ord pair to the next - assumes starting point needs to be repeated as ending point.
function drawPoly(coordStr)
{
    var mCoords = coordStr.split(',');
    var i, n;
    n = mCoords.length;

    hdc.beginPath();
    hdc.moveTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);
    for (i=2; i<n; i+=2)
    {
        hdc.lineTo(mCoords[i], mCoords[i+1]);
    }
    hdc.lineTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);
    hdc.stroke();
}


function myHover(element)
{
    var hoveredElement = element;
    var coordStr = element.getAttribute('coords');
}

function myLeave()
{
    var canvas = byId('myCanvas');
    hdc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function myInit()
{
    // get the target image
    var img = byId('backImage');

    var x,y, w,h;

    // get it's position and width+height
    x = img.offsetLeft;
    y = img.offsetTop;
    w = img.clientWidth;
    h = img.clientHeight;

    // move the canvas, so it's contained by the same parent as the image
    var imgParent = img.parentNode;
    var can = byId('myCanvas');
    imgParent.appendChild(can);

    // place the canvas in front of the image
    can.style.zIndex = 1;

    // position it over the image
    can.style.left = x+'px';
    can.style.top = y+'px';

    // make same size as the image
    can.setAttribute('width', w+'px');
    can.setAttribute('height', h+'px');

    // get it's context
    hdc = can.getContext('2d');

    // set the 'default' values for the colour/width of fill/stroke operations
    hdc.fillStyle = 'red';
    hdc.strokeStyle = 'red';
    hdc.lineWidth = 2;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myInit();" bgcolor="#000000">
<canvas id="myCanvas">Your browser doesn't support canvas.</canvas>
<div class="container">
<img src="myBack.jpg" id="backImage" alt="myBack" width="100%" usemap="#textmap">
<div class="toptext">Top text</div>
//IMAGE MAP
<map name="textmap" id="backMap">
<area shape="poly" coords="606,783, 610,768, 621,634, 617,617, 625,566, 632,484, 625,461, 635,453, 635,437, 648,425, 650,391, 694,388, 699,403, 716,422, 708,426, 718,440, 734,444, 763,553, 750,564, 746,628, 764,705, 829,774, 825,784, 606,783" href="1.htm" target="_blank">
<area shape="poly" coords="752,637, 756,626, 756,581, 774,529, 780,469, 803,456, 806,448, 806,437, 786,442, 744,426, 772,405, 795,395, 800,396, 805,360, 809,338, 826,336, 833,350, 852,349, 855,361, 850,362, 845,357, 824,362, 826,372, 842,360, 827,376, 844,367, 829,380, 837,377, 829,384, 837,386, 846,380, 873,385, 864,414, 834,429, 831,440, 837,446, 864,461, 877,509, 860,528, 857,544, 832,561, 828,548, 813,546, 809,549, 814,573, 814,580, 830,592, 853,598, 853,585, 867,575, 870,589, 879,596, 879,614, 881,625, 870,676, 863,707, 864,726, 877,734, 892,747, 900,750, 902,759, 883,769, 880,783, 833,779, 832,768, 785,723, 763,685, 752,637" href="1.htm" target="_blank">
</map>
</div>

//FAMOUS PLUGIN FOR MAP RESIZING
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var ImageMap = function (map) {
            var n,
                areas = map.getElementsByTagName('area'),
                len = areas.length,
                coords = [],
                previousWidth = 1600;
            for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                coords[n] = areas[n].coords.split(',');
            }
            this.resize = function () {
                var n, m, clen,
                    x = document.body.clientWidth / previousWidth;
                for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                    clen = coords[n].length;
                    for (m = 0; m < clen; m++) {
                        coords[n][m] *= x;
                    }
                    areas[n].coords = coords[n].join(',');
                }
                previousWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                return true;
            };
            window.onresize = this.resize;
        },
        imageMap = new ImageMap(document.getElementById('backMap'));
    imageMap.resize();
}
</script>

//DYNAMICALLY RESIZE BACKIMAGE
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("backImage").style.width=window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById("backImage").style.height=window.innerHeight;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.container {
position: relative;
}

.toptext {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 30px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
font-size: 18px;
}

#myCanvas {
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
}
```

EDIT:
I modified the code as this, but it is still not working:

HTML/JavaScript

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Homepage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="homestyle.css" type="text/css">

<script>
var hdc;

function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

function drawPoly(coordStr)
{
    var mCoords = coordStr.split(',');
    var i, n;
    n = mCoords.length;

    hdc.beginPath();
    hdc.moveTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);
    for (i=2; i<n; i+=2)
    {
        hdc.lineTo(mCoords[i], mCoords[i+1]);
    }
    hdc.lineTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);
    hdc.stroke();
}

function myLeave()
{
    var canvas = byId('myCanvas');
    hdc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function myHover(element)
{
    var hoveredElement = element;
    var coordStr = element.getAttribute('coords');
    drawPoly(coordStr);
}

function myInit()
{

    var img = byId('backImage');

    var x,y, w,h;

    x = img.offsetLeft;
    y = img.offsetTop;
    w = img.clientWidth;
    h = img.clientHeight;

    var imgParent = img.parentNode;
    var can = byId('myCanvas');
    imgParent.appendChild(can);

    can.style.zIndex = 1;

    can.style.left = x+'px';
    can.style.top = y+'px';

    can.setAttribute('width', w+'px');
    can.setAttribute('height', h+'px');

    hdc = can.getContext('2d');

    hdc.fillStyle = 'red';
    hdc.strokeStyle = 'red';
    hdc.lineWidth = 2;
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="myInit();" bgcolor="#000000">
<canvas id="myCanvas">Il tuo browser non supporta i canvas. Ci dispiace!</canvas>
<img src="sfondoprof.jpg" id="backImage" alt="sfondoprof" width="100%" usemap="#textmap">
<map name="textmap" id="backMap">
<area shape="poly" onmouseover="myHover(this);" onmouseout="myLeave();" coords="606,783, 610,768, 621,634, 617,617, 625,566, 632,484, 625,461, 635,453, 635,437, 648,425, 650,391, 694,388, 699,403, 716,422, 708,426, 718,440, 734,444, 763,553, 750,564, 746,628, 764,705, 829,774, 825,784, 606,783" href="1.htm" target="_blank">
<area shape="poly" onmouseover="myHover(this);" onmouseout="myLeave();" coords="752,637, 756,626, 756,581, 774,529, 780,469, 803,456, 806,448, 806,437, 786,442, 744,426, 772,405, 795,395, 800,396, 805,360, 809,338, 826,336, 833,350, 852,349, 855,361, 850,362, 845,357, 824,362, 826,372, 842,360, 827,376, 844,367, 829,380, 837,377, 829,384, 837,386, 846,380, 873,385, 864,414, 834,429, 831,440, 837,446, 864,461, 877,509, 860,528, 857,544, 832,561, 828,548, 813,546, 809,549, 814,573, 814,580, 830,592, 853,598, 853,585, 867,575, 870,589, 879,596, 879,614, 881,625, 870,676, 863,707, 864,726, 877,734, 892,747, 900,750, 902,759, 883,769, 880,783, 833,779, 832,768, 785,723, 763,685, 752,637" href="1.htm" target="_blank">
</map>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var ImageMap = function (map) {
            var n,
                areas = map.getElementsByTagName('area'),
                len = areas.length,
                coords = [],
                previousWidth = 1600;
            for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                coords[n] = areas[n].coords.split(',');
            }
            this.resize = function () {
                var n, m, clen,
                    x = document.body.clientWidth / previousWidth;
                for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                    clen = coords[n].length;
                    for (m = 0; m < clen; m++) {
                        coords[n][m] *= x;
                    }
                    areas[n].coords = coords[n].join(',');
                }
                previousWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                return true;
            };
            window.onresize = this.resize;
        },
        imageMap = new ImageMap(document.getElementById('backMap'));
    imageMap.resize();
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("backImage").style.width=window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById("backImage").style.height=window.innerHeight;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
position: relative;
}

.toptext {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 30px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
font-size: 18px;
}

#myCanvas {
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you call drawPoly function. I'm guessing you need to call it from myHover and add an event listener for mouse enter to your element and call myHover function

Comment: Oh thank you! I added the call and the event listener, but it seems it's not working

Comment: I've just edited my initial post

Comment: So do you still have a question? I put your code on jsfiddle, it's working fine. Open the developer tool on chrome, you'll see your hover and leave functions are firing. https://jsfiddle.net/yc1k66cL/1/

Comment: If you can provide an link image it would be easily to determine your code (don't have to be your image but something similar to what your trying to do).

Comment: I've put the source of my image in the main question post

Comment: Adding your most recent update to a fiddle works fine. Maybe you just need to update the line color. https://jsfiddle.net/7qu7tdxu/

Comment: Kodecount, thanks for your reply. Just one more question: the highlighted border doesn't dynamically resizes or moves as the image map itself. How can I make this happen?