# can't position canvas over image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm trying to draw some stuff over loaded image. However, for some reason canvas appears below the image not on top. I'm doing it as follows:

I have the following container:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='nature.jpg')}}" id="target" style="zIndex=1">
</div>>
```

And the I'm trying to add canvas as follows:

```
  window.onload = function() {
    var img = document.getElementById('target');
    var width = img.naturalWidth;
    var height = img.naturalHeight;

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); //Create a canvas element
    //Set canvas width/height
    canvas.style.width=width;
    canvas.id = 'mycanvas';
    canvas.style.height=height;
    //Set canvas drawing area width/height
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    //Position canvas
    canvas.style.position='absolute';
    canvas.style.left=0;
    canvas.style.top=0;
    canvas.style.zIndex=100000;
    canvas.style.pointerEvents='none'; //Make sure you can click 'through' the canvas
    $('#container').append(canvas);
}
```

However, canvas appears below the image rather than on top of it. What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Can you share jsfiddle?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag/12667751#12667751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the wrong syntax for the inline style `style="zIndex=1"`, it should be `style="z-index: 1"`, still, for `z-index` to work its element need a position other than `static`

In this case, since the `img` has no position, you can actually drop the `z-index` all together, as the canvas has a position, `position: absolute`, and will be layered on top of the image because of that alone.

For the `canvas` to be positioned relative to the `container`, the `container` need a position, i.e. `position: relative`