# Need Best Answer for Image Map with Multiple Rollover Hotspots

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemap, maphilight

It seems that using jquery.js and jquery.maphilight.js would be the best solution for my rollover map project, however I cannot seem to make it work.  I am trying to follow the very basic example posted here: https://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/  The "Simple Demo" under "Demos" shows exactly what I want to do, and I think I am following the code exactly to try and duplicate.  Here is what I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.map').maphilight();
    });   
</script>    
</style>
</head>
<body padding="0" margin="0">

<img class="map" src="township-range-test.jpg" width="1400" height="1050" usemap="#countymap">

<map name="countymap">
<area shape="rect" coords="329,530,504,714" title="29-13" href="javascript:alert('Navigate to ITORIAN');" data-maphilight='{"fillColor":"0000ff","fillOpacity":0.3}'>
<area shape="rect" coords="504,530,692,714" title="29-12" href="javascript:alert('Navigate to GOOGLE');">

</map>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a copy of the jquery.js and the jquery.maphilight.js scripts in the same directory as my test web page here:

https://www.sanjuantitle.com/sj-county-map-java.html

If you roll your mouse over the square "29N-13W" the link works fine, and also the link works for the square to the right of that "29N-12W". So the only thing that is not working is the rollover "hilighting" that works just fine on the demo page I mentioned above.

I'm sure that it's something simple I'm missing, but I have gone over it several times and cannot find the flaw in my code.  I would appreciate any suggestions and help.  Thanks.

Comment: image....map? did I go through some sort of time portal on my way back from the bathroom?

Comment: try this https://www.image-map.net/

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
<img src="https://www.sanjuantitle.com/township-range-test.jpg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_parent" alt="here's google" title="here's google" href="google.com" coords="126,135,325,333" shape="rect">
    <area target="_parent" alt="here's more google" title="here's more google" href="google.com" coords="324,338,503,522" shape="rect">
    <area target="_parent" alt="here's stackoverflow" title="here's stackoverflow" href="stackoverflow.com" coords="89,867,506,529,680,856,884,524,1050,868,1109,518,1070,954,1127,1004" shape="poly">
    <area target="_parent" alt="yahoo?" title="yahoo?" href="yahoo.com" coords="809,236,344" shape="circle">
</map>
```

Comment: I realize this doesn't satisfy the "hover" portion of your question. For that you will indeed need a javascript solution. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag