# How to adding hover efect for image area mapping

Tags: html, css

How can I add effects to the code below? Should I do using javascript and css...Please help me.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Mapping Hover</title>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
#area1, #area2, #area3, #area4 {
 opacity: 0.8;
 transition: all .3s;
}
</style>

<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" width="300" height="300" usemap="#Map"/>
<map name="Map">
<area id="area1" shape="rect" coords="108,140,200,264" href="#">
<area id="area2" shape="rect" coords="9,140,101,264" href="#">
<area id="area3" shape="rect" coords="108,7,200,131" href="#">
<area id="area4" shape="rect" coords="8,7,100,131" href="#">
</map>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Html is here.

Comment: What kind of hover effects are you trying to have happen?

Comment: only want to make opacity

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667751/9422637)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the following code out of the body Tag

```
<style type="text/css">
#area1, #area2, #area3, #area4 {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all .3s;
}
</style>
```

And I suggest you give the value of class to div and try 'div class.hover #image' in the style.
For example,

```
<style type="text/css">
.container:hover #area1{
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all .3s;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
```

Comment: Did you even try this ?

Comment: unfortunately it does not work.