# Blinking border for image mapping

Tags: html, css

I want blinking border for image mapping

I want through CSS. I want rectangular borders to blink permanently around map areas.

HTML

```
   <img src="images/glass.png" alt="" class="img-responsive glass-image" usemap="#jazzmap"><br>
  <map name="jazzmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="140,56,190,96" href="" alt="Video" title="Video" class="wp-video-popup" >
  </map>

  <img src="images/prices.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" usemap="#bookingmap">
 <map name="bookingmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,150,178,185" href="#" alt="Book Now" title="Book Now" class="sg-popup-id-89">
 </map>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink { 50% { border-color: #F00; }  }
map { 
border: 1px solid #FFF  ;
-webkit-animation: blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;  
}
```

It is not showing the blinking borders in white and red alternate.
Any help?

Comment: remove `-webkit-`

Comment: Not working by removing -webkit-   Also tried giving css to "area"

Comment: you removed ALL the webkit? you have 2 in your code

Comment: I'm sorry -- removed map > area with map

Comment: It is not showing rectangle.  Also there are 2 mappings in same html.  only 2 lines at bottom are blinking

Comment: I want rectangular border around each mappings

Comment: You want an area of the map to have a blinking border, or the whole map ?

Comment: Only the area and not whole map

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply Hovering on html area tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661124/how-to-apply-hovering-on-html-area-tag)

Comment: 1 mapping has 1 area only

Comment: I want it permanently blink around the areas -- hot hover

Comment: Why do you need a map if there's only one area ?

Comment: only portion of images have mapping -- not the entire images

Comment: As you might know, the map doesn't cover the image it just generates invisible elements `(area)` from the shapes you defined and puts them on the image, so you can't define styles on the map and expect it to style that area, and also areas are not style-able.

Comment: so your best bet to is to have a mask for that image with a border cover that area and add it as animation to the img not the map

Comment: yes thank you for that  -- i wanted to simplify it because of the responsive issue

Answer (score 0):

This example is working for me ....

```css
 @-webkit-keyframes blink { 50% { border-color: #ff0000; }  }

img{ 
 border: 4px solid  ;
 position: fixed ;
 top: 10px ;
    left: 10px ;
 text-align:center ;
 font-family: monospace ;

 -webkit-animation: blink .5s step-end infinite alternate; 
}
```

```html
<img class="border0" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
```