# Changing color of specific part in graphicImage

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I need to change the color of a specific part of a graphicImage when a button is clicked. I am using JSF, Primefaces, and CSS.

I positioned the image using:

```
<h:graphicImage url="/resources/imgs/img.png" style="margin-top: 15%; width: 100%;"/>
```

I tried to put a primefaces p:panel inside the graphicImage:

```
<h:graphicImage url="/resources/imgs/img.png" style="margin-top: 15%; width: 100%;" >
    <p:panel style="background-color: red;"/>
</h:graphicImage>
```

But it does not show up **inside** the image. Is it possible to put something "inside" the image? Using this, when the page is resized, the component should resize within the image.

Comment: Images can't have contents so you can't put anything inside them.

Comment: why not replace the image on button click?

Comment: @TimGerhard because there are a lot of parts in the image that I want to change the color when a button is clicked. And there are a lot of buttons (each one controls one part of the image), so I would need a lot of combinations (and images) to represent that.

Comment: @Paulie_D So is there something to do about it? Maybe position the panel above the image? The problem is that I need the panel to resize exactly the same way as the image.

Comment: Try in plain html and extrapolate to JSF... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

Comment: Sounds like a job for SVG

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906734/visible-area-tag

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to simply edit th epicture by itself. Photoshop offers a 7 day free trial. Download it, and add the border or your color overlay to the part of the image and instead of the original image running, set the background to change when it is hovered upon or clicked. Your question was not clear so I do not know exactly what you want.

Comment: @Azync, please do not spam the comment section, this is a productive website that is not supposed to be filled with spam.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah What spam? Please do not post unrelated things in the comment section.

Comment: @Azync Your ten deleted comments were not gone unnoticed.